# How do I receive and use webhook data sent from Mailgun?

Tags: php, json, api, webhooks, mailgun

I am using webhooks from the MailGun API to notify me when an email has been delivered.

I used the RequestBin service to see the data that is being sent:

```
domain: domain.com
token: 6o02nxnu-7grjkvkzxdyn2lsm0w7fagidgxzon8-cucz8u15w0
signature: a4d27e390495691fb4b8fb76b3b8a71c90cf8cd467140f5c3d36e023ec343e5c
Message-Id: <20140721155006.120305.72293@domain.com>
timestamp: 1405957808
X-Mailgun-Sid: WyJjZjMyNCIsICJjaHJpc3NlY2tsZXJAZ21haWwuY29tIiwgIjAxNzBiNSJd
message-headers: [["Received", "by luna.mailgun.net with HTTP; Mon, 21 Jul 2014 15:50:06 +0000"], ["Content-Type", ["multipart/alternative", {"boundary": "21586684bc984a0cbc485d4a862fc34c"}]], ["Mime-Version", "1.0"], ["Subject", "Please Check Your Account"], ["From", "Sender Name <testemail@domain.com>"], ["To", "Chris <anotheremail@gmail.com>"], ["X-Mailgun-Sid", "WyJjZjMyNCIsICJjaHJpc3NlY2tsZXJAZ21haWwuY29tIiwgIjAxNzBiNSJd"], ["Date", "Mon, 21 Jul 2014 15:50:08 +0000"], ["Sender", "testemail@domain.com"]]
recipient: email@domain.com
event: delivered
```

I am now trying to use their information sent via a POST array and insert it into my DB.

The following variables I can grab directly from the POST array that they are sending:

```
$recipient_email = $_POST['recipient']; //This works
$timestamp = $_POST['timestamp']; //This works
```

The following variables I cannot get to directly from the POST array. They are within a datatype in the "message-headers" variable that I am not familiar with. How can I access those?

```
$sender_name = ?;
$sender_email = ?;
$recipient_name = ?;
$subject = ?;

$sql = 'INSERT into mail SET
        from_name = "'.$sender_name.'",
        from_email = "'.$sender_email.'",
        to_name = "'.$recipient_name.'",
        to_email = "'.$recipient_email.'",
        subject = "'.$subject.'",
        date = "'.$timestamp.'"';

$result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Comment: can you just log the $_POST variable like `error_log(json_encode($_POST));`? and check what data you get it in log file.. you can `tail -f` log file.. :)

Comment: There is a detailed guide here: http://blog.mailgun.com/a-guide-to-using-mailguns-webhooks/

Answer (score 1):

Well, the `message-headers` are an  array of arrays. For each sub-array the first item (key `0`) is the "label", the second item (key `1`) is the "value". So you could do something like this:

```
foreach ($POST['message-headers']} as $i => $header) {
    switch( $header[0] ) {
        case 'Subject'
            $subject = $header[1];
            break;
        case 'Sender'
            $sender_email = $header[1];
            break;
        /* Any other cases that I'm too lazy for now ...*/
    }
}
```

(although building up a map of `$header[0]` vs variable name and then simply looping without the `switch` might be somewhat easier to read, but that's just my taste.)

But PLEASE parameterize the SQL query! Otherwise you will get hacked in no time at all.

Answer (score 0):

This what I have done in Django app..

I was just logged all post dat into the log file and monitor it using tail command

> 1) may be you can do same in PHP like logging the code into the error log
>
> 2) error_log(json_encode($_POST));
>
> 3) check monitor the post data which you received from the mailgun
>
> 4) and use the required params :)

Here is the python code:

```
    sender    = request.POST.get('sender')
    recipient = request.POST.get('recipient')
    subject   = request.POST.get('subject', '')

    body_plain = request.POST.get('body-plain', '')
    body_without_quotes = request.POST.get('stripped-text', '')
    body_html = request.POST.get('body-html', '')
```